# How to show error after layout change

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to have admin section, my code looks like:

```
// app/routes :: Admin root
Router::connect('/:controller', array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/:controller/:action', array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

and

```
// in Controller/AppController.php
    public function beforeFilter() {
        if (isset($this->params["prefix"]) && $this->params["prefix"] == "admin") {
            $this->layout = "admin";
        }
    }
```

and i have 2 layout default.ctp and admin.ctp

The problem is, the errors not shown when the layout change with beforeFilter function(like syntax error in admin controller). How to handle this problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your layout(admin.ctp)

```
<?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
```

Comment: still not work, i have syntax error in AdminController.php like (public function view _active() {
  
 }
)
but error still not showup when i add beforeFilter in AppController

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i changed beforeFilter to beforeRender thats it